# Choose which Firestore database to connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Firestore databases in my google cloud "default" and "mydb". When I set up my spring boot app to connect to the database it always connect to the "default" one. How to connect to the "mydb" database in my spring boot app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use a code snippet similar to what's shown in the Firestore documentation on [initializing the client](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library#initialize), but then in the builder make sure to [call `setDatabaseId`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/3.15.0/com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.Builder?hl=en#com_google_cloud_firestore_FirestoreOptions_Builder_setDatabaseId_java_lang_String_) passing in the database ID of the instance you want to access.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Is there a way of using this (FirestoreOptions) and  FirestoreReactiveRepository from "spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore" at the same time? I mean customize FirestoreReactiveRepository to use the firestore I connected with FirestoreOptions.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used `FirestoreReactiveRepository` and don't quickly see examples of how to use it, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: No problem Frank. Thank you very much for you help.